# render all records in a stored procedure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stored-procedures

I am trying to render all the data of a stored procedure in a table in my view but the problem is that the name of the columns can change in each stored query so I can not make the specific field call in the render because each query brings different columns, how could I make the call of the columns name for the  (table titles) and render all the data in the  unspecified in the name of the data but bring all the results of the query that apparently returns them in an array?

this is my stored_procedures_controller.rb

```
class StoredProceduresController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_usuario!


  def cantidad_productosxpedido
    @cantidad_productosxpedido = Stored_procedure.fetch_db_records("exec SPAD_ReporteProductosxPedido '#{Time.now.try(:strftime,"%Y%m%d")}','#{params[:search]}','#{params[:search6]}'")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.xls
    end
  end

end
```

this is my model stored_procedure.rb

```
class Stored_procedure < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.fetch_db_records(proc_name_with_parameters)
    connection.select_all(proc_name_with_parameters)
  end

  def self.insert_update_delete_calculate(proc_name_with_parameters)
    connection.execute(proc_name_with_parameters)
  end

  def self.fetch_val_from_sp(proc_name_with_parameters)
    connection.select_value(proc_name_with_parameters)
  end

end
```

I usually do the rendering of the stored this way

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover rwd_auto">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Ruta</th>
        <th>Pedido</th>
        <th>IdCliente</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Nombre Comercial</th>
        <th>2010100</th>
        <th>2020100</th>
        <th>2020200</th>
        <th>2020500</th>
        <th>2021200</th>
        <th>2200500</th>
        <th>2200501</th>
        <th>2200508</th>
        <th>2200509</th>
        <th>2201000</th>
        <th>2203100</th>
        <th>2203101</th>
        <th>2203102</th>
        <th>2203104</th>
        <th>2203108</th>
        <th>2203200</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody id="container_productosxpedido">
    <%= render partial: "/stored_procedures/cantidad_productoxpedido", collection: @cantidad_productosxpedido %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and in the partial _cantidad_productoxpedido

```
<tr>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['Ruta'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['Pedido'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['IdCliente'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['Cliente'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['NombreCorto'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['2010100'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['2020100'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['2020200'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['2020500'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['2021200'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['2200500'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['2200501'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['2200508'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['2200509'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['2201000'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['2203100'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['2203101'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['2203102'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['2203104'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['2203108'] %></td>
  <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido['2203200'] %></td>
</tr>
```

but when changing the name of the columns I do not know how to do to display the data without specifying the names of those columns

UPDATE

I could resolve to display the contents of the table as follows

```
  <%@cantidad_productosxpedido.to_a.each do |foo|%>
          <tr>
            <%foo.each do |label, value|%>
              <td><%= value %></td>
            <%end%>
          </tr>
        <%end%>
```

but now I try to add the headers of the table 
like this:

```
  <%@cantidad_productosxpedido.first.each do |foo|%>
      <tr>
        <%foo.each do |label, value|%>
          <th><%= label %></th>
        <%end%>
      </tr>
  <%end%>
```

but it does not show correct in the table  but renders it as follows

```
<tr>
     <th>title1</th> <td>value1</th>
</tr>
<tr>
      <th>title2</th> <th>value2</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: What do you want the output to show?

Answer (score 0):

`object.attributes.keys` will return an array of column names for a given record. You can use that to generate your columns as follows:

```
<% @cantidad_productosxpedido.each do |cantidad_productoxpedido| %>
  <% cantidad_productoxpedido.keys.each do |col| %>
      <td><%= cantidad_productoxpedido[col] %></td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Not tested, but that should work.

Comment: hey thanks, I got the following error with your code: ActionView :: Template :: Error code (undefined method `attributes' for # <Hash: 0x862e003c>):
  but I could solve it, but I'm trying to show the headers, I updated my post adding details at the end